# Call search scroll API with SAME scroll_id, but response parameter `hits.total.vaule` changes

Tags: elasticsearch

I am suffering this strange behaviour of ES.

1. Call scroll search API with SAME scroll_id from many times.
2. Mostly, the parameter in response named `hits.total.value` keeps unchanged.
3. But some time, this parameter changed between 2 sequence API calls.
4. Of course, SMAE scroll_id are passed with these 2 API call.

Is there any possible situations which would lead to this behaviour?

Comment: Hi @hamidbayat thanks for your update. Would you please elaborate this more? for example, share a link about this?